# VSTS On-Premises - Dashboard Reporting Capabilities

Tags: azure-pipelines

We use VSTS On-Premises to manage our sprints, work allocation, progress etc.  We've customised some of the generic templates (user story, task etc.) to add additional attributes with a view to providing real-time dashboards, tailored to specific stakeholders.

I find the out of box reporting capabilities in VSTS quite limited, and am struggling to find any alternatives.  I'm new to this area so just wondering if anyone can point me to an extension or any resource that offers rich reporting capabilities.  I think the out of box query builder and charts are limited in grouping etc.  Any pointers at all welcome, liker I said new to this so may be missing something obvious.  Thanks.

Considering BI reports but not sure how advanced it is, and how easy to integrate into the VSTS dashboards

Answer (score 0):

You can use power bi to create stunning reports to discover new insights and improve performance .

For the advanced analytics with power bi  ,you can refer to this [introduction](https://www.marquam.com/Documents/Advanced%20Analytics%20with%20Power%20BI%20White%20Paper.pdf) .

About the integration of Power BI into azure devops , you can refer to this official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/overview?view=azure-devops).

The Analytics service is generally available for all organizations using Azure DevOps Services. It provides several [advanced widgets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/dashboards/analytics-widgets?view=azure-devops).